# Unable to update address space on Azure vnet using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

**Objective**: I am trying to update existing address space (4 ranges) as it was wrong cidr range given when creating it orginally

**Context**: Existing vnet consists of address_space as

```
["xx.xxx.0.0/24","xx.xxx.0.0/20","xx.xxx.0.0/24","xx.xxx.0.0/20"]
```

Now, I changed this to

```
["xx.xxx.0.0/24","xx.xxx.0.0/24","xx.xxx.0.0/24","xx.xxx.0.0/20"]
```

But when I rerun my terraform, plan does not pick this up as change. By the way, this is not having any vnet peering

**The code that I use for creating Vnet :**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.hub_vnet_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].name
  address_space       = var.vnet_address_space
  dns_servers         = var.dns_servers
  tags     = {
    environment = "${var.env}"
    costcentre = "xxx"
  }
  dynamic "ddos_protection_plan" {
    for_each = local.if_ddos_enabled

    content {
      id     = azurerm_network_ddos_protection_plan.ddos[0].id
      enable = false
    }
  }
}
```

**Varaibles.tf:**

```
variable "vnet_address_space" {
  description = "The address space to be used for the Azure virtual network."
  default     = ["xx.xxx.0.0/24","xx.xxx.0.0/24","xx.xxx.0.0/24","xx.xxx.0.0/20"]
}
```

Really not sure why terraform is not able to see this change, can some one guide
no there is no erros it says during the plan

Comment: Do you have a root module, where the variable is also set? Are you sure, the new value is handed to the vnet resource? Another tests would be, to hardcode the values directly on the resource, to isolate the variable-handling, and of course update/downgrade providers.

Comment: @burna you are right, when I assigned values directly instead of variable then it recognize the change.. as I have only main (root module only) i have defined like in above original post example, not sure why its not taking when I am passing it via variable value